# Is there an example in CPAN of a module that implements a REST based API using modern Perl techniques?

Tags: perl, rest

I would like to create a module for the [Pinboard API](http://pinboard.in/api).
Though very similar to the old Delicious API, there are enough changes that I would like to re-implement to specifically work for Pinboard.

The [`Net::Delicious`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aDelicious) module was build initially in 2002 and I see that many of the newer REST best Modules are implemented in a new way.  [`Net::Twitter`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aTwitter), [`WebService::Dropbox`](https://metacpan.org/module/WebService%3a%3aDropbox) and [`WWW::Vimeo::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/release/WWW-Vimeo-Simple) seem to have different methodologies on how to implement their respective REST API.

`Net::Twitter` is very complex and heavy implementation in my opion.  `WebService::Dropbox` is extremely light as is the API it implements.  `WWW::Vimeo::Simple` seems to be between the two in terms of complexity.

I also spent some time looking at [`REST::Client`](https://metacpan.org/module/REST%3a%3aClient) but it probably would not be useful if you want to implement more that one or two methods.

What are the best practices for implementing a complete REST webservice?  and also to test the responses without being able to connect to the service.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is [Net::HTTP::Spore.](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aHTTP%3a%3aSpore) It's a moosy framework for REST clients in modern Perl. See also [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/franckcuny/sporefosdem)